# Why GloVe model (by gensim) does not have vectors for numbers 1, 2, ...?

Tags: word-embeddings, word2vec, tokenization

I expected GLoVe to have vectors for numbers.

```
from gensim import downloader as api
glove = api.load("glove-twitter-25")
glove['1']
```

This results in `KeyError: "Key '1' not present"`

Does GLoVe ignore numbers? Or are they somehow tokenized?

Interesting that there are vectors for single letters like "a" or even "i"

Answer (score 0):

It does have vector representation for numerics in arabic and other languages. Type this:

```
for e in glove.index_to_key :
    try : 
        int(e)
        print(type(e))
        print(e)
    except :
        pass
```